# Why does this getter return undefined?

Tags: javascript, getter

Here's an example of a getter that iterates over an array and is expected to return an element for which `a` is `true`. But `test.active` returns `undefined`.

```
var test = {
  arr: [
    {id: 1, a: false},
    {id: 2, a: false},
    {id: 3, a: true},
    {id: 4, a: false},
    {id: 5, a: false},
  ],
  get active() {
    this.arr.forEach(item => {
      if(item.a) return item
    })
  }
}
```

Why?

Comment: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is the correct method to use here. `return this.arr.find(item => item.a);`

Comment: what if more than one element has `a === true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement is in an *inner* function, causing that function to return. Your outer function does in fact return nothing.

If you want the outer function to return, use a normal `for` loop instead.

```js
var test = {
  arr: [
    {id: 1, a: false},
    {id: 2, a: false},
    {id: 3, a: true},
    {id: 4, a: false},
    {id: 5, a: false},
  ],
  get active() {
    for (var i = 0, e = this.arr.length; i < e; i++) {
      var item = this.arr[i];
      if (item.a) return item;
    }
  }
}

console.log(test.active);
```

It might help if you understood how `forEach` works.

Internally, it looks much like the following, though this is *very* simplified.

```js
function forEach (array, block) {
  var i, length = array.length;
  
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // This is where your return would end up, unused, in a different context.
    block(array[i], i);
  }
}


forEach(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], item => {
  return 'is meaningless here';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to test for a given condition and return the found element.

```
var test = {
  arr: [
    {id: 1, a: false},
    {id: 2, a: false},
    {id: 3, a: true},
    {id: 4, a: false},
    {id: 5, a: false},
  ],
  get active() {
    return this.arr.find(item => {
      return (item.a === true);
    });
  }
}

alert(test.active.id)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arqxcbkv/1/